# Are the states of a quantum system enumerable?

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I know that there exist some quantum systems with an enumerable amount of states.

I know that quantum systems are somehow composed of smaller quantum systems which can interact.

Are these quantum systems with an enumerable amount of states the only quantum systems that exist or are there quantum systems with a continuum of states?

If so, what are the names of such quantum systems?

Comment: I saw the question you posted earlier. I don't think you decided to listen to what the people there advised you. A better question might be for some simple, super foundation QM book. Maybe even just a popular science book that uses words to explain the simpler concepts rather than maths

Comment: Following the advice and doing this is not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @Nick Asking informal questions like these in a formal environment like physics.stackexchange.com allow me to see which formal terms and concepts are important to understand these simple questions.

Comment: That's OK. I just thought of a book that might be a good idea for you. Principles of quantum mechanics by Dirac. It gets very complicated later on but it begins very conversational, having full pages of total prose. It introduces the bra ket notation in a simple manner (this was made by Dirac and is the most widely used notation at the moment). I'm not sure what level maths your at, but if you've done vectors you should be relatively OK (kets=vectors). Could always skip the mathsy bit there and focus on his prose. Can find a pdf on google easily

Answer (score 2):

> Are the states of a quantum system enumerable?

In general, no.

The simplest quantum system I can think of with a continuum of states is a free particle in an infinite space.

If you want something less trivial, but still simple, the scattering states of an electron and a proton form a continuum. Only the bound states (i.e., those of a hydrogen atom) are discrete and enumerable.

> I know that quantum systems are somehow composed of smaller quantum systems which can interact.

Quantum systems are not necessarily composed of smaller interacting quantum systems. It’s not “[turtles all the way down](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)” in the theories of fundamental physics that are currently accepted. For example, in the Standard Model of particle physics, an electron is not composed of anything simpler.

Comment: I think one should add that technically the state space is not enumerable even for a 2-level system. However, OP's questions seems to be about the countability of a basis of the Hilbert space, e.g. the energy eigenstates, which is the question you answered here.